# HTTP Response is always 200 when it should be >400

Tags: security, http

I am apologize early and I hope I am in the correct forum, I am working on a Test Automation team working with Selenium/Java and I build a Test against a website to check for broken urls, by checking HTTP responses.  My question is not about my code because I tested it against an external site with a in correct url, proving that I get a 200 when expected and a 404 when expected.

So we are currently writing test automation towards a locally hosted website and Azure hosted sites.  When I run my tests towards azure or locally; I am getting a 200 OK for all responses, even when I add a broken url with in my test data.  My question is why would IT/Network environment implement this? Security? F5 Load Balancer? WAF? What I am looking for is a where(Device? Appliances?) and Why?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The
[Azure Functions JavaScript developer guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node)
lists the following:

> isRaw Indicates that formatting is skipped for the response.

I think you need to set it for your answer to be passed as-is.